# Error Installing amd_catalyst-13.12 Driver

Tags: linux, driver

Today i've downloaded new AMD Catalyst driver, and when the installation process, an error message appears "**there were errors during installation**"  here is step for the installation of me:
**sudo update && sudo upgrade done, reboot.

- uninstall AMD Catalyst old driver (AMD_Catalyst-13.4):

  ```
  $ sudo sh /usr/share/ati/amd-uninstall.sh
  ```

  restore of system environment completed
  done

  (without errors)
- reboot
- install new driver

  $ sudo sh amd-catalyst-13.12-linux-x86.x86_64.run

installation process error: http://postimg.org/image/675x7cio9/

here is the **fglrx-install.log:**

```
Supported adapter detected.
Check if system has the tools required for installation.
Uninstalling any previously installed drivers.

Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.251/source ->
                 /usr/src/fglrx-13.251

DKMS: add completed.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:

cleaning build area....

cd /var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.251/build; sh make.sh --nohints --uname_r=3.2.0-4-686-pae --norootcheck.......(bad exit status: 1)

[Error] Kernel Module : Failed to build fglrx-13.251 with DKMS

[Error] Kernel Module : Removing fglrx-13.251 from DKMS

Deleting module version: 13.251
completely from the DKMS tree.
Done.
[Reboot] Kernel Module : update-initramfs
```

- reboot, then i can't login to startx
- so i uninstall the new driver, an message error appears:

  $ sudo sh /usr/share/ati/amd-uninstall.sh

  restore of system environment completed

  Error! there are no instances of module: fglrx

  13.251 locate in the DKMS tree

  Error during DKMS module removal

  Uninstall fglrx driver complete

  for detailed log of uninstall, please see /etc/ati/fglrx-uninstall.log

  System must be rebooted to avoid system instability and potential data loss.

here is the **fglrx-uninstall.log:**

```
*** AMD Catalyst(TM) Proprietary Driver Uninstall Log 2013-12-20 13:34:43 ***
Removed /usr/share/applications/amdcccle.desktop
Removed /usr/share/applications/amdccclesu.desktop
Removed /usr/share/icons/ccc_large.xpm
Removed /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_cs.qm
Removed /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_da_DK.qm
Removed /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_de.qm
Removed /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_el_GR.qm
Removed /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_es_ES.qm
Removed /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_fi_FI.qm
Removed /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_fr_FR.qm
Removed /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_hu_HU.qm
Removed /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_it_IT.qm
Removed /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_ja.qm
Removed /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_ko_KR.qm
Removed /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_nl_NL.qm
Removed /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_no.qm
Removed /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_pl.qm
Removed /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_pt_BR.qm
Removed /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_ru_RU.qm
Removed /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_sv_SE.qm
Removed /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_th.qm
Removed /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_tr_TR.qm
Removed /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_zh_CN.qm
Removed /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_zh_TW.qm
Removed /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/qt_cs.qm
Removed /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/qt_da.qm
Removed /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/qt_de.qm
Removed /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/qt_es.qm
Removed /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/qt_fr.qm
Removed /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/qt_hu.qm
Removed /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/qt_ja.qm
Removed /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/qt_ja_JP.qm
Removed /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/qt_ko.qm
Removed /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/qt_pl.qm
Removed /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/qt_pt.qm
Removed /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/qt_ru.qm
Removed /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/qt_sv.qm
Removed /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/qt_zh_CN.qm
Removed /usr/share/ati/amdcccle/qt_zh_TW.qm
Removed /usr/bin/amdcccle
Removed /usr/bin/amdxdg-su
Removed /usr/bin/amdupdaterandrconfig
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/ccc_copyrights.txt
Removed /etc/security/console.apps/amdcccle-su
Removed /usr/share/ati/lib/libQtCore.so.4
Removed /usr/share/ati/lib/libQtGui.so.4
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/LICENSE.TXT
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/user-manual/AMD_Linux_Driver_Specification.pdf
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/user-manual/index.html
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/examples/etc/acpi/ati-powermode.sh
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/examples/etc/acpi/events/a-ac-aticonfig
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/examples/etc/acpi/events/a-lid-aticonfig
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/examples/etc/init.d/atieventsd.sh
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/1gbhang.html
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/4461.html
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/4462.html
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/4463.html
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/4464.html
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/4469.html
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/4470.html
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/4475.html
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/4478.html
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/4479.html
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/4480.html
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/4481.html
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/4482.html
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/4483.html
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/4484.html
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/4485.html
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/corruptstereo.html
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/corruptvtswitch.html
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/devshm.html
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/dga3dhang.html
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/doom3corrupt.html
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/dualheadvideo.html
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/laptopsuspend.html
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/missingdrmheaders.html
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/mousecursorhang.html
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/no3d-aiw8500dv.html
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/no3d-kt400.html
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/nomembercount.html
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/pcie3dmemoryleak.html
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/r420blankdisplay.html
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/rv280dviblankdisplay.html
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/rv350springdale.html
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/secondheadcorruption.html
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/xf86_enodev.html
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/xrestartpcie.html
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/articles/xvsatshift.html
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/configure.html
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/driverfaq.html
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/index.html
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/installer.html
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/issues.html
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/linuxfaq.html
Removed /usr/share/doc/ati/tips-linux.html
Removed /usr/share/man/man8/atieventsd.8
Removed /usr/lib/xorg/modules/linux/libfglrxdrm.so
Removed /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fglrx_drv.so
Removed /usr/lib/xorg/modules/glesx.so
Removed /usr/lib/xorg/modules/amdxmm.so
Removed /usr/lib/libAMDXvBA.cap
Removed /usr/lib/libAMDXvBA.so.1.0
Removed /usr/lib/libOpenCL.so.1
Removed /usr/lib/libXvBAW.so.1.0
Removed /usr/lib/libamdocl32.so
Removed /usr/lib/libatiadlxx.so
Removed /usr/lib/libaticalcl.so
Removed /usr/lib/libaticaldd.so
Removed /usr/lib/libaticalrt.so
Removed /usr/lib/libatiuki.so.1.0
Removed /usr/lib/libfglrx_dm.a
Removed /usr/lib/libfglrx_dm.so.1.0
Removed /usr/lib/fglrx/fglrx-libGL.so.1.2
Removed /usr/lib/fglrx/switchlibGL
Removed /usr/lib/fglrx/switchlibglx
Removed /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/fglrx_dri.so
Removed /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/fglrx/fglrx-libglx.so
Removed /usr/include/GL/glATI.h
Removed /usr/include/GL/glxATI.h
Removed /usr/include/ATI/GL/glx.h
Removed /usr/include/ATI/GL/glxext.h
Removed /usr/bin/fgl_glxgears
Removed /usr/bin/fglrxinfo
Removed /usr/bin/aticonfig
Removed /usr/bin/atiodcli
Removed /usr/bin/atiode
Removed /usr/bin/clinfo
Removed /usr/src/ati/fglrx_sample_source.tgz
Removed /usr/sbin/amdnotifyui
Removed /usr/sbin/atieventsd
Removed /usr/sbin/atigetsysteminfo.sh
Removed /etc/ati/amdpcsdb.default
Removed /etc/ati/atiapfxx
Removed /etc/ati/atiapfxx.blb
Removed /etc/ati/atiapfxx.log
Removed /etc/ati/atiogl.xml
Removed /etc/ati/authatieventsd.sh
Removed /etc/ati/control
Removed /etc/ati/logo.xbm.example
Removed /etc/ati/logo_mask.xbm.example
Removed /etc/ati/signature
Removed /etc/OpenCL/vendors/amdocl32.icd
/usr/bin/md5sum: /usr/X11R6/lib/modules/dri/fglrx_dri.so: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/md5sum: /usr/bin/amdconfig: No such file or directory
Removed /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-fglrx.conf
```

- then i reboot, login as usual without amd driver

i've tried install old driver again (AMD_Catalyst-13.4) and nothing happens, the installation process successful, and the driver working well. Anyone get same problem like me  ? any suggestions guys ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are applying patch to **wrong file**. You have to patch `catalyst/common/lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/kcl_acpi.c` instead of `catalyst/ati-installer.sh`

Here is complete procedure from links of Miles Zhang:

```
 1. ./amd-catalyst-13.12-linux-x86.x86_64.run --extract catalyst 
    cd catalyst 
 2. Apply the patch: $ patch -Np1 -i ../looks_like_amd_forgot_this.patch

       File to patch: common/lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/kcl_acpi.c

 3. sudo ./ati-installer.sh 13.251 --buildpkg Ubuntu/saucy 
 4. install the build packages, placed one directory up
```

**UPDATE**
The simplest way is to to delete `catalyst` folder and extract `amd-catalyst-13.12-linux-x86.x86_64.run` archive again.

Comment: thanks man, it's works, i've successfully patching the file, i think i was made a mistake choosing a wrong file :)

Comment: i've extract the file already, then how to make an archive .run file, i don't know :(

Comment: ju dont have to, just run `catalyst/ati-installer.sh`. its same as running original `.run` file

Comment: Just an additional point, I had to install the following dependent packages in order to compile the driver: `sudo apt-get install build-essential debhelper dh-modaliases libqtgui4 execstack`.

Answer (score 1):

Google gives me these linkes:

http://phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?91885-AMD-Catalyst-13-12-GPU-Driver-For-Linux-Released&p=381954#post381954

http://phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?91885-AMD-Catalyst-13-12-GPU-Driver-For-Linux-Released&p=382324#post382324

Comment: thanks @Miles Zhang, but still not working for me. I was following this guide http://phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?91885-AMD-Catalyst-13-12-GPU-Driver-For-Linux-Released&p=381957#post381957 and here is the result of mine:   

http://pastebin.com/swNAbPmw

Comment: I applied the patch manualy. This worked for me https://gist.github.com/moldcraft/8116528

Comment: This driver is not stable at all. After some minutes my pc crashes with black screen, and some times shows me log in screen, some times just freeze in that black screen. I moved back to the latest beta.